# Get URL response code with JavaScript on Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I've got a Google Sheets doc with a list of URLs and I need to check the response code of each of them.

I know that there's a possibility to write a script with JavaScript and then run it as a Sheets function.

Can anyone help me by providing a JS script that takes an URL and returns whether it's a 200, 3XX, 4XX...

So far I've done this:

```
function getStatusCode(url) {
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {"muteHttpExceptions":true}).getResponseCode()
 return response;
}
```

This works fine so far, if you have a better solutions I'm open!

Thanks!

Comment: You want to minimize your network requests, so if you are going to leverage the data later on in your workflow, you should write this in a more robust fashion. That way it is just 1 call, as opposed to 2.

Comment: Can I ask you about your goal? 1. If you are using `getStatusCode` as a custom function, are you required to use the function as the custom function? 2. Can I ask you about the number of URLs you want to check?